# Dynamic column alias based on column value

Tags: mysql, dynamic, alias

I want to name the column alias based on the column value in mysql. Is that possible?

Something like this;

```
select  
  case when answer_type = 'RB' then 
     answer_type as 'radio'
 else 
     answer_type as 'evrything_else'
 end case
from  XTable
```

Comment: you need to create dynamic query if you want to have dynamic alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible in pure SQL. You'll probably have to query the data out and then process it in whatever application is executing the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select if(answer_type="RB",true,NULL) as radio, 
if(answer_type != ="RB",true,NULL) as everything_else
from XTable;
```

You have to split them as you get a table for a result where the names or aliases from the select are the column labels.    This method lets you check the value of radio (and the value of everything_else) that gets returned.

What you're trying to do,  see there's no way to make the column header work:

```
id | radio MAGICAL OR everytning_else |
1  | RB                               |
2  | NOT_RB                           |
```

What my method will do for you:

```
id | radio | everything_else |
1  | true  | NULL            |
2  | NULL  | true            |
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this solution. But I was wondering a way to do this in single column

Answer (score 0):

select if(answer_type="RB",'radio',if(answer_type != "RB",'everything_else',NULL)) as answer_type from XTable;