# Split Query Result into Virtual Columns based on Value

Tags: sql, db2

I have an existing database that has column values abstracted out to a separate 'values' table (for localization reasons, but not necessarily important in the context of this question).  In my case, say I have two tables:

```
***ITEM Table***

id    cat  
----|-----|
1   | A   | 
2   | A   |
3   | B   |

***VALUES Table***

seq   id    code   value   type
----|----|-------|-------|-------|
10  | 1  | NAME  | Name1 | Type1 |
11  | 1  | DESC  | Desc1 | Type1 |
12  | 1  | NAME  | Name1 | Type2 |
13  | 1  | DESC  | Desc1 | Type2 |
14  | 2  | NAME  | Name2 | Type1 |
15  | 2  | DESC  | Desc2 | Type1 |
```

Currently, I can retrieve names and descriptions like this:

```
***Current Result Set***

id    code    value   
----|-------|-------|
1   | NAME  | Name1 |
1   | DESC  | Desc1 |
2   | NAME  | Name2 |
2   | DESC  | Desc2 |
```

However, I would like to retrieve names/descriptions like this:

```
***Target Result Set***

id    NAME    DESC   
----|-------|-------|
1   | Name1 | Desc1 |
2   | Name2 | Desc2 |
```

I thought a CTE/Window function may be appropriate in this case, but I'm not sure how to tackle this.

**In essence, how can I create column aliases and associated values, based on a value in a column (in this case, if the 'code' column contains 'NAME', a virtual 'NAME' column would be created, with the value from the associated 'value' column)?**

I considered a CASE statement too, but couldn't use it to create a dynamic alias like this.

If this is impossible, as in ([Dynamic column alias based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423572/dynamic-column-alias-based-on-column-value)), would it be possible to do this if I knew of the "CODE" values ahead of time (i.e. I know that only "NAME" and "DESC" are valid codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need the data to be pivoted , you can use CASE for this with MAX aggregate function.

if you know the values in advance, it can be coded like this

if the values are dynamic then dynamic sql is preferred.

```
SELECT I.ID,
       MAX ( case when code = 'NAME' THEN V.value end ) as 'NAME',
       MAX ( case when code = 'DESC' THEN V.value end ) as 'DESC'
FROM ITEM I
INNER JOIN VALUE V
ON I.id = V.id
GROUP BY I.id
```

Comment: Really close, but I forgot to mention that there could be more than one 'NAME' or 'DESC' associated to a given item, so the MAX won't necessarily work as mentioned here.  There is another column that classifies these values even further (a "TYPE").

Comment: I guess I could either include this TYPE in my predicate OR include additional conditions in my CASE

Comment: @spary02, you can type to group by and also to select clause