# MySQL - Filter Column Multiple Times

Tags: mysql

I'm exporting content from an old, low-adoption CMS. I'm getting stuck linking some information related to my main resources.

One main table, "resources," has books, etc. listed with titles, year of publication, etc. I want to create a table with one record per resource, plus related info from other tables in new columns.

Another table, ResourceNameInts, links the resources table to multiple types of metadata (i.e. authors, language, formats). These are just ID #s that link to a table of controlled names ("ControlledNames"). There are also multiple instances of each data type for each title in resources. (For example, multiple authors, publishers, and formats.) So a book can have one line in the resources table and multiple relationships in ResourceNameInts. For now I'll just group them together with GROUP_CONCAT; I could parse those later if I want.

I want to create multiple columns filtering ResourceNameInts but I can only get one column to work (i.e. creating a "Publishers" column based on ID# 19):

```
SELECT r1.title, GROUP_CONCAT(c.ControlledName SEPARATOR '; ')
FROM resources r1
RIGHT JOIN resourcenameints r2 ON r1.ResourceId = r2.resourceid
RIGHT JOIN controllednames c ON c.ControlledNameId = r2.ControlledNameId
WHERE c.FieldId=19
GROUP BY r1.title
```

I want to create a column for each data type (one for ID#19, then one each for #s 20, 23, 24, 25, and 26). But I can only use one WHERE statement. I've tried using IF or CASE for each column instead, for example:

```
SELECT r1.title,
(CASE c.fieldid WHEN 19 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(c.ControlledName SEPARATOR '; ') END) AS publisher,
(CASE c.fieldid WHEN 20 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(c.ControlledName SEPARATOR '; ') END) AS author
FROM resources r1
RIGHT JOIN resourcenameints r2 ON r1.ResourceId = r2.resourceid
RIGHT JOIN controllednames c ON c.ControlledNameId = r2.ControlledNameId
WHERE c.FieldId=19 OR c.FieldId=20
GROUP BY r1.title
```

...but I'm not getting the right results - the "publisher" column is populated but the other columns show up as NULL. I also tried a nested SELECT query:

```
SELECT r1.title,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.ControlledName SEPARATOR '; ') WHERE c.FieldId=19 GROUP BY r1.title) AS publisher,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.ControlledName SEPARATOR '; ') WHERE c.FieldId=20 GROUP BY r1.title) AS creator
FROM resources r1 RIGHT JOIN resourcenameints r2 ON r1.ResourceId = r2.resourceid RIGHT JOIN controllednames c ON c.ControlledNameId = r2.ControlledNameId
GROUP BY r1.title
```

but that doesn't seem to filter the columns correctly.

Do I need additional syntax for IF or CASE, or is there another technique I don't know about?

Comment: Don't think that is possible. Have a look at this SO answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423572/dynamic-column-alias-based-on-column-value

Comment: Thanks. If that's the case, at least I'm not missing anything. The thread you referenced suggested exporting data first - not an optimal solution but might have to do as a workaround.